# Ubuntu hotspot limit devices to LAN access

Tags: networking, ubuntu, hotspot

I have set up a WiFi hotspot on my Ubuntu machine (using the builtin hotspot tool), to share connection to some wireless devices.
Now I would like to restrict some of those devices (IP range, or MAC address) to only access LAN but not the internet (I have a regular router where no settings like this is possible, the Ubuntu machine is connected to this through ethernet).
I checked things like ufw, or iptables but with no success.
Can you suggest how I could achieve this (either with different network topologies).
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

The question is more than one year old but still seems to be releavnt. You may use "iptables" to block particular users from going outside your LAN by

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i <wlan interface> -o <LAN interface> -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j REJECT
```

In the above example, the wlan interface amd the LAN interface could be "wlan0" and "eth1", respectively. Moreover, "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" denotes the MAC address of the user to be blocked. To unblock the user again, use:

```
iptables -L FORWARD --line-number | grep XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX | awk '{print "sudo iptables -D FORWARD " $1}' | sh
```